# How do I to Identify top 3 customers in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, join

I'm trying to identify the top three customers (owner_id) based upon how many visits they've had to a dog_salon business.

Some owners have more than one pet, so I want to add up all of their visits across all pets. The top three customers (owner_id) should be listed in descending order according to number of visits (use the alias num_visits)!
I have four tables owners, owners_2, transactions, and visits.

- `owners` has 3 columns. owner_id, pet_id, and size *(owner_id is different in owners and owners_2 table)*
- `owners_2` has 3 columns. owner_id, pet_id, and size
- `transactions` has 4 columns. transaction_id, date, pet_id, and service
- `visits` has 2 columns. pet_id and visits_count

This is the formula I tried to no luck.

```
SELECT
    owners.owner_id, owners_2.owner_id, owners.pet_id, owners_2.pet_id, 
    COUNT(visits.visits_count) AS num_visits 
FROM 
    owners 
INNER JOIN 
    owners_2 ON owners.pet_id = owner_2.pet_id 
INNER JOIN 
    visits ON visits.pet_id = owners_2.pet_id 
GROUP BY 
    owners.owner_id, owners_2.owner_id, owners.pet_id, owners_2.pet_id 
ORDER BY 
    visits.visits_count 
DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Why do you have two `owners` table? What's the difference between `owners` and `owners_2`

Comment: The owner_id is different in both tables

Answer (score 0):

If our `owners` and `owners_2` are just two owners table containing different owners, you can union all them before joining to the `visits` table like in the following

```sql
with all_owners as (
select owner_id, pet_id from owners union all
select owner_id, pet_id from owners_2)

select owners.owner_id, sum(visits.visits_count) AS num_visits
from all_owners owners INNER JOIN visits on visits.pet_id=owners.pet_id
group by owners.owner_id
ORDER BY 2 desc desc
limit 3
```